# Обновление таблицы БД одним запросом

Tags: php, mysql

Есть сводная (pivot) таблица со следующей структурой:

```
 id  | post_id | user_id | score
  1  |   20    |   10    |  10000
  2  |   20    |   11    |  12000
.... |  .....  | ......  | .......
  n  |   n     |    n    |    n
```

Данная таблица будет обновляться cron'ом каждые 5 минут. Данные для обновления формируются в массив из JSON-файла. Сделано это для того, чтобы убрать дополнительную нагрузку с БД, поскольку предположительно нужно будет производить не менее 50000 операций обновления с периодичностью от 1 до 5 минут.

Вопрос мой в том, как мне обновить данную таблицу одним запросом, потому что 50000 запросов как-то многовато =) Или может быть подскажите еще какое решение для реализации данной задачи. Заранее спасибо!

UPD: Под "обновлением" - я имел ввиду: "Замену страых значений, и если не нашлось совпадения - добавление нового".

UPD2: Данная таблица просто хранит лучший счет участников и представляет собой таблицу некоего турнира. При активации участника в турнире, его id заноситься в эту таблицу и счет присваивается 0. Таким образом, мы понимаем, что пользователь активировался и участвует в этом турнире. Далее, от участника турнира может приходить результат с разным периодом времени, но не дольше 1 раз в 5 минут. Результат записывается в JSON, cron'ом вызывается метод, который делает выборку из JSON'а и преобразует её в массив. Вот этот массив желательно бы записать в БД одним запросом.

Comment: "Обновление" - это удаление всех данных и вставка новых? Или замена существующих значений? В любом случае mysql поддерживает пакетные запросы (или как их там): `INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (данные_первой_строки), (данные_второй_строки), ...`. Т.е. можно обновлять/вставлять, например, по 1К строк (может больше, не знаю сколько максимум будет). А можно сформировать sql-файл и сказать mysql использовать его: `mysql < new_data.sql` - тогда все за раз вставится

Comment: Ок, переформулирую вопрос: есть записи (1,2) и (2, 2). У нас есть новые данные (2, 3). Что должно быть с (1, 2)? Если у вас таблица топ-рейтингов, то (1, 2) надо удалить (она уже не в рейтинге). Если, например, таблица опыта, то надо оставить запись (просто опыт не изменился, но он же никуда не пропал). На "обновление одним запросом" как бы не влияет, но влияет на генерируемый SQL. Либо `truncate table_name; insert into...`, либо `insert into on duplicate key update...`. Вместо `insert into .. on duplicate` можно и `replace` использовать, здесь скорее дело вкуса

Comment: для быстроты вставки заменить JSON на формат для  LOAD DATA INFILE. вставлять во временну таблицу в памяти, а потом удалить из этой таб. совпадающие , далее insert ....select из этой таблицы

Comment: @ВОРОН Duplicate key - идея хорошая, и надо будет обязательно попробовать, единственное я не понял, он работает в случае, если в таблице указанный уникальный индекс? Или можно использовать без указания уникального индекса?

Comment: Если по факту меняться будут несколько десятков записей, а не все 50к, то никто не мешает держать в памяти отсортированный индекс и  не забывать сортировать данные с json. В этом случае все будет упираться в сортировку и скорость вставки/обновления данных.

Если база не будет успевать - можно делать шардинг - разделит данные на несколько баз.

Но для начала я бы написал алгоритм в лоб (то есть, как Вам попроще) и посмотреть на скорость. Может оно за 10 секунд обновит и Вам этого будет достаточно.

Comment: @Scrobot, из названия следует, что срабатывать будет только при дублировании ключа, поэтому уникальный ключ все же нужен (зачем вам две записи с одинаковыми `post_id` и `user_id`?) Здесь не стоит забывать, что PK - тоже уникальный индекс, но у вас он сам генерируется, поэтому вам он не поможет